# How can I integrate Eventbrite sign-ups with existing users on my custom wordpress site?

Tags: api, wordpress, user-management, eventbrite

I have a wordpress site where I have users and want to manage events through eventbrite. I also want to be able to track which users sign up for which events, which users actually check in to events, etc. Ultimately I want my users to log in to my website and see a list of all the events they've attended in the past (with my organization). From there can can submit feedback for events, etc.

What's the easiest way to do this? Is there any way to validate a user at the process of sign-up on Eventbrite? Or do I simply ask for their user_id in a custom form field and hope they didn't mistype it.

Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0):

> Note, I work on the Platform team at Eventbrite

There are multiple questions here:

> I want to be able to track which users sign up for which events,
>   which users actually check in to events, etc

For this you will need to make API requests as yourself, to get information about your specific events and the attendees who have registered for those events.  Specifically, [event_list_attendees](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/) will give you the stats for attendees in a given event, and the barcodes statuses will show you whether someone has checked in.

> Ultimately I want my users to log in to my website and see a list of
>   all the events they've attended in the past (with my organization).
>   From there can can submit feedback for events, etc.

Since you only want the user to interact with *your* events here, the best way to do this is to store all of your events and attendees, and build up what you want around that data.  I don't know of a Wordpress plug-in which will do that out of the box.

Most of the APIs we have now are organizer-centric.  Really, the better way to do this would be to have a user authenticate via OAuth2 and then you could make API requests on their behalf.  We're currently working on a new RESTful API which will better support scenarios like this.